# Jquery 1.11 tabs not reloading content

Tags: jquery, caching, tabs, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache

I am using jquery 1.11 tabs in my application. IE11 caches the content when the Developer Tool(F12) is closed but strangely reloads when the console is open.

Any suggestion how to reload the content irrespective of console open or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in beforeLoad event basically set ui.ajaxSettings.url to the url with a timestamp param. worked for me